# NodeJS post request from C# incomplete data

Tags: c#, node.js, api, post, request

I have an API in C# as the following

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Runs Supply Plan on Hana DB
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <param name="TaskId"></param>
    /// <param name="ScheduleId"></param>
    /// <param name="TaskType"></param>
    /// <param name="Config"></param>
    [Route("api/Tasks/Hana/Run")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void RunHanaTask(TaskConfig Config)
    {

    }
```

So the API expects Config parameter of type TaskConfig which is defined as

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Database Connection information
    /// </summary>
    public Connection CN { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Additional Options
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<String, String> Options { get; set; }
```

So when I call the from POSTMAN with the following parameters:

```
{
"TaskId": 10052,
"RunLogId": 417,
"TaskType": "SupplyPlanExec",
"CN": {
    "Name": "Sample",
    "Host": "34.216.234.224",
    "Port": "30013",
    "User": "AXISUSER",
    "Password": "1n5ynCV!",
    "Schema": "ORBIT_3",
    "AppUser": "AXISUSER"
},
"Options": {
    "PlanName": "This is plan name here!"
}
```

}

When the API is called from POSTMAN the CN and Options are received by the API,
 but when I call the API from my nodejs app using the following code:

```
   request.post(taskObject.remoteURL, { form: postParams }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (response.sstatusCode == 200) {
        deferred.resolve(body);
    } else {
        deferred.reject(error);
    }
})
```

for some reason the CN is passed successfully but the Options object is not passed to the API, I have been struggling with this tried different request libraries on NodeJS but no luck.

Comment: There's an extra space in the `"Options "` key name. Any change that's not there in postman request? I don't think any deserializer (including the C#'s) will trim the keys, and so `"Options"` and `"Options "` end up being different. The later is simply ignored and not mapped in your C# application.

Comment: Oh sorry that was my bad but removed the space, in the example I am using there is no space mistakenly added it in the question